# canvas zoom in partially

Tags: android

I want to zoom in the canvas board partially as the letter tray button will be fixed and the board will be zoom,
The partially coding is as mention below and the screen is fully draw in canvas which can be viewed as mention at the bottom.. please help and thanks for you concern.

```
        public class BoardView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
                {
        class DrawingThread extends Thread implements OnTouchListener {

        public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder holder, Handler handler) {
                    mSurfaceHolder = holder;

        public void setRunning(boolean b) {
                    mRun = b;
                }

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (mRun) {
                        Canvas c = null;
                        try {
                            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                                // System.gc();
                                // c.scale(canvasScaleX, canvasScaleY);
                                // c.save();
                                // c.translate(canvasTranslateX, canvasTranslateY);
                                doDraw(c);
                            }

                            updateGame();
                        } finally {
                            if (c != null) {
                                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            }
                        }
        }

        private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    if (ge == null)
                        return;

                        Rect bRect = new Rect(0, 0, dims.getTotalWidth(),
                        dims.getScoreHeight() + dims.getBoardheight());
                Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.board);
                drawable.setBounds(bRect);

                drawable.draw(canvas);

                Rect tRect = new Rect(0, dims.getScoreHeight()
                        + dims.getBoardheight(), dims.getTotalWidth(),
                        dims.getTotalHeight());
                canvas.drawRect(tRect, fillTrayPaint);

                int topHeight = dims.getScoreHeight() + dims.getBoardheight();
                int bottom = (dims.getTotalHeight() + 5)
                        - (dims.getTotalWidth() / Tray.TRAY_SIZE);
                Rect rect = new Rect(0, topHeight, dims.getTotalWidth(), bottom - 7);
                Drawable drawableTray = getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.strip);
                drawableTray.setBounds(rect);
                drawableTray.draw(canvas);
                        drawTray(canvas);
                drawBoard(canvas);

                // drawScore(canvas);
                drawMovingTile(canvas);
            }


public BoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        // endTurn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.endturn_button_horizontal);
        thread = new DrawingThread(holder, handler);
    }
@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        final float scale1 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        defaultFontSize = (int) (MIN_FONT_DIPS * scale1 + 0.5f);
        thread.setDefaultFontSize(defaultFontSize);
        dimensions = calculateDimensions(getWidth(), getHeight());
        thread.setDimensions(dimensions);

        thread.setRunning(true);

        // if (thread != null && !thread.isAlive())
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

[image: The screen is fully draw in canvas which is mention as below :-]

Comment: I have successfully implemented it... hurrey.... We can simply do it by canvas.clipRect(rectangle), at this point what we are suppose to do is save the canvas canvas.save() and after canvas.clipRect(rectangle) call canvas.restore().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply do it by canvas.clipRect(rectangle), at this point what we are suppose to do is save the canvas canvas.save() and after canvas.clipRect(rectangle) call canvas.restore().

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying something like this:

- Create a bitmap from the canvas you wish to zoom into.
- When rendering that bitmap to the screen, you can change the scr rect
  (which will "zoom" into the bitmap).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can u provide some sample code for zoom in and zoom out for drawable in canvas

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to render your game board into offscreen bitmap and then draw this bitmap at canvas using `Matrix`, so you will be able to change its position and scale.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way because syn. the tray for letter drag and drop should also expand accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this would be to use `Canvas#scale(float scale, int pivotx, int pivoty)` method.  It essentially grows the entire canvas uniformally which really is what zooming is from a 2D perspective.

`canvas.scale(2.0f, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2)` will scale the image by 2 from the center.  `canvas.scale(1.0f, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2)` will shrink it back.

I have never tried this in this context, so if you decide to try it report back the results please! I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: ok it is about full scalling of canvas.. what about partially scalling, is it possible.. ?

Comment: what do you mean by partially scaling ? Scaling a part of a canvas ?

Comment: If you want a sort of magnifying glass type zooming.... I don't quite know how they do that.  If I had to guess, you'd turn your Canvas in to a bitmap (like the others were saying), put it in another view that overlays on top of your game board which then scales and translates that.  You *might* also be able to use `clipRect` to clip an area you want to zoom in to then use `scale`.  `clipRect` prevents drawing around a certain area, but if you draw the board before you call it, then board will still show. Any other drawings will clip within the bounds.